# How to add data by columns in csv file using R?

Tags: r, csv, append

I have information that is contained in vectors, for example:

```
sequence1<-seq(1:20)
sequence2<-seq(21:40)
...
```

I want to append that data to a file, so I am using:

```
write.table(sequence1,file="test.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
write.table(sequence2,file="test.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

But the issue is that this is added all in one column like:

```
1
2
3
...
21
22
...
40
```

I want to add that data in columns so that it ends up like:

```
1         21
2         22
3         23
...       ...
20        40
```

How I can do that using R?

Comment: You can't append columns to a CSV file.  You have to re-write every row each time you want to add a column.  This has nothing to do with R; it's how the file is stored on-disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`write.table` writes a data.frame or matrix to a file. If you want two write a two-column data.frame (or matrix) to a file using `write.table`, then you need to create such an object in `R`

```
x <- data.frame(sequence1, sequence2)
write.table(x, file = 'test.csv', row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

See `?write.table` for a very clear description of what the function does.

As stated by @JoshuaUlrich's comment, this is not really an `R` issue, you can't append a column to a csv file due to the way it is stored on disk.

Answer (score 12):

While you cannot add the column directly on the file, you can read it into a data.frame, append to column to it, and write the result as a csv file:

```
tmp <- read.csv("original_file.csv")
tmp <- cbind(tmp, new_column)
write.csv(tmp, "modified_file.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the file as you go (in a loop for example):

```
seq1<-t(seq(1,20,1))
seq2<-t(seq(21,40,1))

write.table(seq1,"test.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
write.table(seq2,"test.csv",sep=",",append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
```

Then transpose the file at the end.
If you want to do it all at once:

```
test<-t(rbind(seq1,seq2))
write.csv(test, "test.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

Check on the following code,

```
seq1 <- seq(1:20)
seq2 <- seq(21:40)
bind <- cbind(seq1,seq2)
write.csv(bind,file = "Your_path", append = TRUE)
```

This Code Works.