# R: curirous - write.table doesn't append data in new column

Tags: r, csv, write.table

I want to write a file and add new data to it in a seperate column. New data is added multiple times (12). sounds easy and there is lots of solutios available ([use write.table and not write.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-July/245840.html), [how to use write.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079387/how-to-add-data-by-columns-in-csv-file-using-r), [ETH explanation on write.table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)) 
So I tried the following lines of code unsuccessfully. The new data is always added at the bottom of the first column.

```
    write.table(df$c1, file="name.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F, append=T, sep=",")
    write.table(df$c1, file="name.tsv", row.names=F, col.names=F, append=T, sep="\t")
    sapply(df$c1, write.table, file="name.csv", append=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Above codes work for other users. I don't understand why they dont work in my case.

Comment: There is `)` missing on the first line?

Comment: @zx8754 yes thanks. Though that doesn't explain why it isn't working ;-)

Comment: How your `df$c1` looks like? Another approach would be, read the table, cbind the column, write the table by replacing the old one.

Comment: @Jimbou that is an excellent idea. The only issue is that my df is in fact an unequally sized matrix. Above idea was my work around of [this unsolved problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540949/r-repeatedly-cbind-a-matrix-a-vector-of-unequal-length-vector-goes-into-n?noredirect=1#comment64520013_38540949)  R seems to handle unequally sized matrices not well :-(

Comment: @Simone `cbind.na` from the qpcr package could handle your problem. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/cbind.na